# Asp.net MVC , How to return a model in an open modal when failed to save

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a list in my view and each element of the list have a Form which it opens in a modal in my Project, save operation of the form works completely fine when `modelstate` is valid. but I want to implement somehow when `modelstate` is not valid then it returns to the same view with an open modal that all inputs have the last data which user entered.

this is my View

```
@model iranholi.Models.TourRequestViewModel

 <ul>
    @foreach (var tour in Model.Tours)
    {
   <div class="col-md-3" id="inqcol">

     <div>

   @* THIS BUTTON OPENS MODAL *@
    <input data-id="@tour.Id" type="button" class="btn   get-by-ajax inq" value="INQUIRE" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalDate">
     </div>

     <div>
           <p>Cost:</p>
            @tour.Price $
     </div>

 @* HERE IS MY Modal,simplified  *@


     @using (Html.BeginForm("CreateR", "Tour"))
     {
       ....a form which it creates the request model
       <div class="form-group">

           <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default" />
      </div>
     }

 </div>

</ul>
}
```

this is my Controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult CreateR([Bind(Include = "Id,TourId,FirstName,LastName,Email,Phone,Comment,FrequentTraveler,TravelersCount,Date,ContactTimePreference,Country,Archived")] Request request)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Requests.Add(request);
            db.SaveChanges();

            TempData["ResultMessage"] = "Form  Posted successfully.";
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Tour", new { country = request.Country });
        }
        TempData["ResultMessage"] = "Try Again!";
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Tour", new { country = request.Country });

    }
```

How is it possible for if `modelstate` is not valid then then it returns to the same view with an open modal that all inputs have the last data which user entered. I know I need to use java-script and ajax but no idea how . 
Appreciate Any help . thanks

simplifid javascript here

```
 $(".inq").click(function () {

    $("#choosecount").css("display", "none");
    $("#list").html("");
    var numcount;

    var self = this;        
    $.post('/TourDates/GetByTour/' + $(self).data('id'), function (data) {

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

            (function () {
                var date = data[i];
                $('<li/>').html(
                    '<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">' + date.StartDate + '</div>'
                    +
                    '<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-5">' + date.Price + '$</div>'
                    +
                    '<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-1"></div>'
                    ).appendTo('#list').addClass("container-fluid").click(function () {

                        //$("#shownum").html(parseInt(1));

                        numcount = 1;
                        $("#shownum").html(numcount);

                        $("#choosecount").css("display", "block");

                        $("#showdate").html(date.StartDate);                            

                        price = parseInt(date.Price);

                        $("#tpriceforall").html(date.Price + "$");

                    });

            })();
        }
    });
    //here

    $("#plus").click(function () {

        numcount = numcount + 1;

        $("#shownum").html(numcount);

        $("#tpriceforall").html((numcount * price) + "$");

    });

    $("#minus").click(function () {
        if (numcount > 1) {

            numcount = numcount - 1;
            $("#shownum").html(numcount);
            $("#tpriceforall").html((price * numcount) + "$");
        }

    });

});
```

[image]

after next button

[image]

Comment: Why in the world do you have a form for each item in the collection? (you should haveonly one form) And how are you opening your 'modal'.

Comment: @StephenMuecke thank you so much. I update my java-script code. there is a list of tours that when user choose one of them then user should fill the form for that exact tour, do you think i need to change it logically?

Comment: Logically its not making sense. Your controller method suggest you want to redirect when you submit. What is the point of generating a form for each item in the collection. You can only submit one form so you have generated a whole lot of extra html for nothing (and degraded performance in doing so). You might as well render the collectionas display only with a 'Edit' link associated with each item and redirect to a form to edit that item

Comment: yes thanks i think that's much better to use just one form. thank you so much.